# matlab code for DFT steps

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, fft

i want to make a product in frequency domain between filter sobel and image and i cannot get 
the filtered image  what is my problem in this code

```
[A,B]=size(f);
%[C,D]=size(fspecial('sobel'));
h=fspecial('gaussian');
[C,D]=size(h);
hp=freqz2(h,size(f,2),size(f,1));  
'%padarray(h,[ceil(((A-C)/2)) ceil(((B-D)/2))] );
'%hp=hp(1:254,1:256); 
HP=fft2(hp);
HP=ifftshift(HP);
F=fft2(f);
G=HP.*F;   % product of transfer function and image in frequency domain 
g=real(ifft2(G));
imshow(g) % do not work
```

Comment: '  [A,B]=size(f);                                 %[C,D]=size(fspecial('sobel'));                                    h=fspecial('gaussian');                                [C,D]=size(h);                        hp=freqz2(h,size(f,2),size(f,1));  
 '%padarray(h,[ceil(((A-C)/2)) ceil(((B-D)/2))] );   '%hp=hp(1:254,1:256);                                    HP=fft2(hp);                                              HP=ifftshift(HP);      F=fft2(f);             G=HP.*F; % product of transfer function and image infrequency domain g=real(ifft2(G));  imshow(g) % do not work'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `HP=fft2(hp);`, `hp` is already at the frequency domain. Just remove that line, and use

```
HP=ifftshift(hp);
F=fft2(f);
G=HP.*F;   
g=real(ifft2(G));
imshow(g)
```

Comment: thanks for answering but what is the difference between freqz2 and fft2 ?

Comment: in your case freqz2(h)=abs(fftshift(fft2(h)))

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer, so others facing similar problem may have a reference . Thanks

Comment: sorry  ,how can i do so